# How to find a lost ETH

Tags: wallets, wallet-transfer

A bit ago I bought ETH through Coinbase and now I can't find it. I have been trying to hunt it down all day with my luck. My overall knowledge of crypto is limited so I may be doing it wrong.

When I go to the transaction page on Coinbase I am taken to Etherscan and it shows the address I sent it to, within minutes of buying it. I do not remember transferring it that day, but I am sure I could have.

What I do remember is buying a Ledger Nano S to keep it on, with some other coin. I did not receive the Ledger for months after the purchase. When I boot up the Ledger it shows an account for all my various coins. Each account is there, including ETH. But the ETH is the only one with a 0 balance. I transferred less than 1 full coin but there is no part of a coin showing either.

I have been searching all of my paperwork and apps to see where I would have sent it that day. All I have on my PC that could be relevant is a file called wallet which contains an alphanumeric string with over 600 characters.

Is there any way to track this down? Anything I should be looking for?

Comment: Did you download Ethereum-Wallet? Did you generate a wallet file, named like UTC-XXXX.json? Did you use mobile wallets? Did you use an online wallet?

Comment: @Ismael Not that I can remember. This was in Jan 2018. Any other popular ones I should check? I do not have a son file. Does knowing where it was sent help track it to anywhere? Any idea what that wallet file with a bunch of numbers, symbols, and letters could represent?

Comment: Well _a bunch of numbers, symbols, and letters_ could be anything. See [here](https://wizardforcel.gitbooks.io/practical-cryptography-for-developers-book/content/symmetric-key-ciphers/ethereum-wallet-encryption.html#utc--json-keystore---example) for an example of UTC file. It is the most common format for ether wallets. Another alternative is to have a mnemonic of 12 or 24 words.

Comment: @Ismael I know it could be many things and I appreciate your willingness to think through it. This file does not look like this and instead is, like ...hjdgfdisKS&hdgfdk2183... Does knowing where I sent it help identify a wallet I could have used? Is it possible to download the coin and that is what this string represents? Or would I of had to of sent it to a wallet?

Comment: The recipient address doesn't give any information about the wallet used to generate it. The file might look a [bitcoin's wif wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format), but I've never used it with a ethers.

Comment: @ismael So it is not possible that this string is the wallet itself? Do you know the popular wallets in early 2018?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what were the popular wallets in 2018. The wallets I've used support either mnemonics or the json file.